# "Need admin approval" despite all admin permissions are granted

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a client and a server application both registered in AAD. The server application's permissions are the following:

[image: Server permissions]

So the permissions that can't be granted by "normal" users are granted upfront by an admin. On the other hand everything that the user is allowed to grant should not be granted upfront by the admin, but by the user - via the consent screen. So whenever a user uses the app she should need to consent to `Calendars.ReadWrite` and `Contacts.ReadWrite`.

The client only has the permission to access the server API:

[image]

The user tries to get a token via the client application app id using the scope that should allow accessing the whole server API (`api://<server-app-id>/.default`). However when doing that the user doesn't see the consent screen after logging in but the following error screen:

[image]

I don't understand because all super-power-permissions have already been granted upfront by an admin, right? I can "fix" it by doing one of the following, but nothing seems right to me:

- Giving admin consent to the client app permission "user_impersonation". The consent screen then doesn't show because everything is granted.
- Giving admin consent to the rest of the server app permissions (except "offline_access" doesn't need admin consent it seems). The consent screen doesn't show as well.
- Completely removing the server app permissions that need admin consent (*.All). This one even has the desired effect that the consent screen is shown for the two remaining permissions. But of course the server won't be able to use the admin permissions.

I also tried to replace the *.All permissions with (granted) *application* permissions. This resulted in a similar error.

Is it possible to only grant admin permissions and have the non-admin ones granted by the user?

EDIT:
When I try to login to my app using an admin account I don't get the error screen but I have to consent to all permissions - even the ones that should already be granted:

[image]

Looks like admin-granting only a subset of the permissions doesn't work, right?

Comment: Do you want users consent to permissions that do not require the administrator's consent?

Comment: Yes exactly, they should need to consent to `Calendars.ReadWrite` and `Contacts.ReadWrite`.

Comment: When you set the `scope` as the `/.default` when requesting a token, it will ask the administrator to consent to all permissions. Why don't you use dynamic permissions? For example: `api://{server-app-id}/user_impersonation` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/users.Read.All`.

Comment: Please note that do not use `/.default` in the `scope`.

Comment: Ahh that's a good catch. I thought `/.default` is easiest because the client doesn't need to know the exact permissions (the graph api is not called by the client but only later by the service app), but with `/.default` it seems that *all* permissions must be granted, even the ones that have already been granted upfront by an admin. This one says it very explicitely: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope
Can you put that in an answer? I would accept that then.

Comment: I edited the answer, please see the added part in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The user can of course consent to permissions that do not require the administrator's consent, and you can set it in the Azure portal.

- Sign in to the Azure portal as a Global Administrator.
- Select Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > Consent and
  permissions > User consent settings.

[image]

---

**Add**：

The `/.default` scope is usually used in v2.0 endpoints, and the `/.default` scope can be used in any OAuth 2.0 flow. However, the `/.default` scope is not mandatory. It is generally used in the following two authentication flows:

1. **Client credential flow**. If your permissions are [application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types), you must use the `/.default` scope, because the application permissions do not involve users, so the administrator must agree to all application permissions.
2. **OBO flow**. Because the OBO flow involves the middle-tier, you must use `/.default` to pre-authorize all permissions.

Since you are currently using delegated permissions, so you do not need to use the `/.default` scope.

Comment: Thanks, but that is already set up. That is the one thing I found all over the internet. But if that wasn't correctly set up, it wouldn't work, even if I removed the admin permissions, right? (see last bullet point in the OP)

Comment: @JohannesEgger  Are you talking about canceling the administrator's consent?

Comment: No, if I completely remove the three *.All permissions, the consent screen is shown for the two remaining permissions - so of course that's not an option, because the server needs those permissions later.

Comment: @JohannesEgger  Why do you want to delete the three `*.All` permissions?

Comment: @JohannesEgger  Can you explain your thoughts to me? If you only want ordinary users to consent to non-administrator permissions, then you can refer to my answer.

Comment: @JohannesEgger  Administrators can grant to administrator permissions and non-administrator permissions, and users can only grant to non-administrator permissions. You cannot set "Administrators can only grant to administrator permissions but not non-administrative permissions"!

Comment: My problem is that currently normal users are not even asked to grant to ordinary permissions. But that's only the case if the app also has some admin permissions defined. It looks like as soon as the app defines admin permissions, I need to give admin consent to *all* permissions. I can't have admin grants for admin permissions and user consent for ordinary permissions.

Comment: @JohannesEgger  No, the administrator can only consent to the administrator permissions. You only need to run the [administrator consent  url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) in the browser, then you can make the administrator only consent to the administrator permissions. This kind of consent is called dynamic consent.

Comment: @JohannesEgger  In addition, ordinary users can of course consent to permissions that do not require the consent of the administrator. I just did a test https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9nV6.png.    By the way, ordinary users cannot use the administrator consent url.

Comment: @JohannesEgger  Also, when you grant users consent, make sure you have completed the settings I provided in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the admin consent url for the three admin permissions. I consented to them using an admin account. When I then try to login using a normal account I still get the error screen saying "Need admin approval".

Comment: @JohannesEgger  Are all users in one tenant? Are you saying that after you have granted the administrator consent, you are still prompted "need admin approval " when you log in as a ordinary user? Which authentication flow are you using?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same tenant as the app is registered in. Yes, exactly, I see "need admin approval" despite all three admin permissions being granted by a tenant admin. The client uses the authorization code flow (I think), and the service uses the On-Behalf-Of flow (but I get the error message before calling my service api).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now I'm not sure if I can get around the `/.default` route because the server uses OBO flow to get its own access token, or is there another way?